# Center <td> using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to center some inputs inside a table and set a size to this td using bootstrap (on angularjs) but I can't make it work !

What I have now:

```
<div class="container">
    <form class="form" data-ng-submit="salvarPartida()">
        <table class="table table-bordered" align="center">
            <tr data-ng-repeat="partida in partidas | filter : {fase : fase}">
                <td style="height: 30px; text-align: right; font-size: 10pt;">{{partida.time1.nome}}
                    <img data-ng-src="/images/bandeiras/{{partida.time1.imgNumber}}.png" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                </td>
                <td  class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="col-xs-3" >
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <br>
                <td  style="height: 30px; text-align: left; font-size: 10pt;"><img src="/images/bandeiras/{{partida.time2.imgNumber}}.png" title="{{partida.time2.nome}}" 
                    style="vertical-align: middle;"> {{partida.time2.nome}}</td></tr>
                </table>
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Salvar</button>
                <br>
                <br>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Which looks like: [image: this]

But my expectations are : [image: expectations]

Nevermind the color styles, I'd like just to proper align all fields !

I've tried using align="center" on the , class="text-align" inside the td class, also tried creating a  nested into this  using the previous text-center class but no luck !

My jsfiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vea5G/)

Thanks so much.

Comment: use `align="center"` attribute in `td`...

Comment: simple as that wrap the text box in a div give the td containing the textboxes align="center"

Comment: I've tried that, no luck. Also, the spacing problem is not resolved.

Comment: give a fiddle with your code

Comment: with bootrap there is no need to use table for layout bootsrap itself provide css classes for that purposes

Comment: what would recommend then user3127499 ? Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container m-con">
<form class="form" data-ng-submit="salvarPartida()">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr data-ng-repeat="partida in partidas | filter : {fase : fase}">
            <td class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <div class="row m-row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-push-8 text-right">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" height="50"  width="50" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-lg-8 col-sm-pull-4 m-text text-right">
                        Brazil                           
                    </div>

                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>                
            </td> 
            <td class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <div class="row m-row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 text-right">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" height="50"  width="50" />
                    </div> 
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-lg-8 m-text text-left">
                        Brazil                           
                    </div>                        
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Salvar</button>        
</form>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.m-con {
    margin: 20px;
}

.m-text {
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-top:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.m-con td {
    vertical-align:middle !important;
}

@media screen and (max-width:765px) {
    .m-row > div {
        text-align:center;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vea5G/2/

Comment: what is **m-text** in `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-lg-8 m-text text-left">`?

Answer (score 22):

Centering `<td>` using bootstrap is simple:

- horizontally:

`<td class="text-center">`

- vertically:

`<td class="align-middle">`

Answer (score 0):

```
//use td is padding
 td{
     vertical-align:middle;
     padding:10px 20px;
     width:1000px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding up custom CSS:

**HTML**

```
               <div class="col-xs-3 max-center" >
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 max-center">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.max-center {

  text-align:center;
}
```

You can also try adding additional padding to the cells on the sides, but I'm not sure how much because I don't have the images. Just be careful, it can mess up the layout.